# How many 301 redirects can I point to a page without hurting SEO?

Tags: seo

I have several pages with the same topic, but different content that I write every year on a WordPress site, but because the information is useful for an exact period of time, instead of keep creating different pages every year, I thought on consolidating the pages into one master-page and keep updating it every year, instead of creating more pages.

So the question is how many 301 redirects can point to a page without hurting the SEO of the site with search engine?

I have around 5 topic that I would like to simplify with a master-post. One of the topics would have 15 redicters to the main page, and the other 4 topics would less than 6 redirects.

Is it better this way or it's better to delete the pages using 410 code?

Also, is there a rule of thumb of how many redirects can you use per day?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no limit to the number of HTTP 301 redirects and this number does not impact SEO.
The only thing to avoid is too many redirect for the same page (i mean redirects in series) because it produces a lack of performance (loading speed) and so it damages the user experience.
Between choosing 301 rather than 410, you just need to know that a page with enough traffic should be redirected (HTTP 301), instead a page without traffic can be definitely closed (HTTP 410).

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use more than 5 redirects in a redirect chain. Google Bot will not follow 301 redirects over multiple hubs.